# PHP GD Functions not being recognised

Tags: php, gd, image-resizing

So Im trying to make a script that uses PHP GD to upload and resize an image. Then save it to the database. I used the SImpleImage.php found here:

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

And implemented the code using the following script:

```
 $myfilename=$_POST['attachments'];

require('SimpleImage.php');

  $image = new SimpleImage();
  $image->load($myfilename);
  $image->resizeToWidth(150);
  $image->save('small-'.$myfilename);

  $image->load($myfilename);
  $image->resizeToWidth(230);
  $image->save('big-'.$myfilename);
```

myfilename is a variable attached to a form field. Ive been playing about with it, and made sure my server has GD installed, and that the SimpleImage.php file is uploaded correctly. But I keep getting loads of errors.

```
Warning: imagesy(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in (File Path).php on line 77
```

All of them relating to SimpleImage.php, which I did not write, seems like it makes sense, and that I know other people have implemented successfully. The majority of the errors are to the one above. Does anyone have any ideas where this problem may be stemming from?

Comment: Its a windows server, not Ubuntu.

Comment: Open your php.ini file and make sure that `extension=php_gd2.dll` is enabled (does not have ";" in front of it). Also, make sure that PHP has enough memory to process your image, so check the `memory_limit` directive in php.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a file from a HTML form with $_POST.
To upload a file you need this field in your form:

```
<input type="file" name="attachments">
```

In your PHP script you have to change the first line:

```
$myfilename=$_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'];
```